# Regular Expression is capturing the beginning word and not the group I want

Tags: regex

I have to parse data that looks like this:

```
bestPerDoseProductByContract":{"code":"1245678" ...<lots of characters here>... "indicator":"blue"
```

Now this repeats in like so...

```
bestPerDoseProductByContract":{"code":"87654321" ...<lots of characters here>... "indicator":"green"
```

and so on.

I want the `\d+` value (in this case `87654321`) wherever it is found in with a 'green' indicator

What I have tried is this..

```
bestPerDoseProductByContract":{"code":"(\d+).*"indicator":"green"
```

But this captures from the very beginning value.  The DOT and STAR is the issue.  I ONLY want to capture where the expression starts with `bestPerDoseProductByContract":{"code":"` .... and ends ends with `"indicator":"green"`.   I want the digit value `(\d+)` of the 'GREEN'.   What I'm getting is the first digit value it runs across.

I'm not that fluent with Reg Exp but have looked into Boundry Words, Start of String (this was wrong).

Any explanation on a fix is highly appreciated.

Comment: In what language? Sounds like you should parse the JSON and navigate through it instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that `.*` is the problem, because it's *greedy* (consumes everything it can while still matching).

Use a negative lookahead so you don't run past a `"indicator"` with your `.*`, like so:

```
bestPerDoseProductByContract":{"code":"(\d+)((?!"indicator").)*"indicator":"green"
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/xDJk6I5Gbmy7bu).

This `(?!"indicator")` is a *negative lookahead*, and means "the next characters must not be `"indicator"`.

Applying this to `.` changes dot from matching anything, to matching anything *except* the leading `"` of `"indicator"`, thus the match never spans multiple bestPerDoseProductByContracts.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!  I did try using that ?! but I KNOW i wasn't utilizing it correctly... I will digest what you have given cause this will come in EXTREMELY handy in near future needs... Thank you so much for your help, information and direction.

Comment: @user3880668 If an answer best answers your question, you should [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it by clicking the big tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i have accepted the solution for this BUT have another issue.   Similar to the format above but this time the regexp is not working, so something is telling that the .)* is not working correctly, I have tried applying this differently and even trying some of the other grouping constructs but with no luck.  Is there another way to select all the 'junk in between the 2 values?  I still need to keep the start of this as similar bestPerDoseProductByContract":{"code":"(\d+) and end as "indicator":"green"... but something in between is causing issues..

Comment: I am going to see what I can do to remove any company sensitive out and leaving the format and allow you to see what I'm up against.  Please give me some time to get this in place.

Comment: ok guys, I was looking for a way upload a text file with the information... this thing is literally 6,581 characters long and that is JUST section I need to capture.. how do I post that information in here?

Comment: the regexp is the same except in the beginning I need this now:
bestValuePricePerDoseDocument":{"code":"(\d+)((?!"indicator").)*"indicator":"green"

Comment: Hey Bohemian.. I think I have it:
bestValuePricePerDoseDocument":{"code":"(\d+)((?!indicator":").)*"indicator":"green"

i have a FULL set of returned raw data and that code above worked.   I have mess with the ?!value as seen above.  this worked in the RegExp101 Tester.  So sorry have to bothered you but again HIGHLY appreciate you leading me in the direction to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to capture anything else with that regex, you can simply use this:

```
\d+(?=.*"indicator":"green")
```

Its a simple positive lookahead, which

> Asserts that the given subpattern can be matched here, without
>   consuming characters

The good thing about this solution is that, if `...<lots of characters here>...` includes `"indicator"` for some reason, it still works.

You can check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/RcUJk6/2) and test it with the other lines you are computing. This site is generally very helpful when you need to figure out a regex.